# Modify Posts from Custom_Post_Type within the plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, posts, custom-field

I've created a plugin, that registers a custom_post_type. This custom_post_type also has custom_fields. The data I've put in the custom_fields should be showed in the post (in the frotend, for the users). 
I want my plugin to be completly independent of the template. To do this, I need to access the posts in the plugin itself and put the information from the custom_fields on the bottom of the posts. I dont want to modify any of the "normal" posts, just those of the custom_post_type.

Sadly I have no idea how to do this. I've managed to do that with an if(custom_field != '') but had to access the template do so. But thats not a "clean" and "nice" solution I think.

That's why I have some questions:

1. Is it "good" or "allowed" to alter posts within a plugin, without accessing the template?
2. If not, how should I alter the posts then?
3. If so, can you give me any examples how to so? Maybe a link to a tutorial or just some code snippets?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `the_content` filter to add your fields to the output of `the_content()` function:

```
function wpd_content_filter( $content ) {
    if ( 'your_custom_type' == get_post_type() ){
        if( $meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'foo_meta', true ) ) {
           $content = $content . $meta;
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpd_content_filter' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. So i just tried it out, but it doesnt worked. Need I add something to it, except of changing "your_custom_type" and "foo_meta"?

Comment: Nvm: That is the perfect solution. Thank you very very very much. You really helped me out with that :)))))